# Statistically independent probability question

Tags: probability, independence

The question says: A survey found that $40\%$ of late trains were late in May and that $15\%$ were late on the 15th day of a given month. Also, it was found that $4\%$ of late trains were late on the 15th day of May.

$1)$ What is the probability that a train is late in May but not on the 15th day.

$2)$ Are the events 'Train late in May' and 'Train late on the 15th day of a month' statistically independent?

Final question in textbook set of questions, that I couldn't solve.

My attempt:

$P(A):$ train late in May $= 0.4$
$P(B):$ train late on 15th day of a month $= 0.15$
$A ∩ B = 0.04$

So I thought that the answer to $1)$ was $0.4-0.04=0.36$ ; however, I'm not sure whether the other days in the month are relevant

For $2)$ I did $0.4 \times 0.15 = 0.06$ ; Since $0.06\ne 0.04$ they are not statistically independent.

Are both these answers correct, or is there something I've missed?

Comment: Please include what you have tried so far/where you are stuck

Comment: Which textbook?

Comment: I drew a venn diagram with 0.36 (A) in one side, 0.11 in the other and 0.04 in the middle. Based on this I thought the answer to the first question was simply 0.36, but I'm not convinced. For the second part, I did p(a intersection b)=0.04 and 0.4 x 0.15 = 0.06. I'm unsure if this is valid proof

Answer (score 0):

(a)

Since there are $31$ days in may, the probability that a train is late in may is $$(0.4)(31) = 0.04 + 30P\\ \frac{(0.4)(31)-0.04}{30}=P\\0.412=P$$ Therefore the probability that a train is late on any given day except for the 15th is $41.2\%$

(b)

My guess is yes, they are statistically independent. However, I would let someone else answer this one as I do not have a source to back it up.

Comment: I think the OP meant that 40% of all late trains were late in May, rather than 40% of all trains in May were late. I'm not completely sure on that, though.

Comment: To clarify yes I meant '40% of all late trains were late in May'